# Fasterxml Jackson primitive boolean serialization

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, fasterxml

I'm using Fasterxml Jackson 2.2.2

I have a simple pojo with a `boolean` (primitive) attribute. When the default `BeanSerializer` and `BeanPropertyWritter` try to serialize it, this attribute is skipped when its value is `false`.

I want:

```
{"id":1, "enabled":false}
```

What I get is:

```
{"id":1}
```

The code in `BeanPropertyWritter` is:

```
// and then see if we must suppress certain values (default, empty)
    if (_suppressableValue != null) {
        if (MARKER_FOR_EMPTY == _suppressableValue) {
            if (ser.isEmpty(value)) {
                return;
            }
        } else if (_suppressableValue.equals(value)) {
            return;
        }
    }
```

I've debugged it and found that `BeanPropertyWritter._suppressableValue` equals `Boolean(false)`, so when a false boolean arrives to this block, it just returns and no output is returned.

What are my options? Can I configure the attribute's writter to un-set its `_suppressableValue`? What would be the easiest and simpler solution?

Comment: It is really weird. It should works. Could you show your entity class and how do you serialize this entity? For me it works. My entity: class 'Entity { private long id; private boolean enabled; getters/setters } 'and smy serialize code: 'new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(entity)'

Comment: Is your field inclusion set to `JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_DEFAULT`?

Answer (score 3):

As was suggested, your `ObjectMapper` settings are probably non-default, and specify inclusion strategy of `NON_DEFAULT`.

But you can add `@JsonInclude` to override this either on your POJO class, or even for boolean property itself: make sure to use `Inclusion.ALWAYS`.